# How to dynamically adjust org chart positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an org chart and you can see some sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hFaQd/).  I have some challenges with this however.

The first challenge is that when the available width is less than the width of the row, it wraps and then the lines are all messed up.  Is there a way to force it to stay on the same line and just add a horizontal scrollbar?  Not the ideal solution, but would at least keep the layout in tact.

The second challenge is having rows of the same level linked to the parent.  All those "Test Name" would link to the applicable "Test Subcompany" using a side line.  I am not sure where to start with this.

The third challenge is having each level centered.  I was thinking about:

```
.orgChart ul li {
   float: left; //remove
   display: inline-block; //add
}
```

but that causes other issues.

Any help on either one of these would be appreciates. Thanks.

Comment: Try http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos it has everything you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep on the same line, I needed to use white-space: nowrap and convert the li's to inline-block.  One thing to note about this is that any white space before and after li's showed a break in the line, so I had to remove those.  I also had to add vertical-align: top to make sure that the lines stayed attached if the li's were different heights.  This also fixed the centering issue.  Still not sure about the multiple rows of items, but this at least works as a solution for now.

```
.orgChart ul {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.orgChart ul li {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see the revised fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hFaQd/2/).